# define a POM property regarding the type of project version

Tags: maven-2, properties

I would like in a maven2 POM to define a property with a different value if I am packaging a SNAPSHOT or a RELEASE (a non SNAPSHOT) of my project.

I know that I can write a simple Mojo plugin that defines the property regarding the project.version (contains SNAPSHOT or not), but I cannot imagine that in the Maven's hell of existing plugins there is not already one that I could use.

If you know a way of doing this, I would appreciate your help.

Matthieu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want would be done using the Maven2 profiles management. As you can see [here](http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.0.4/maven-model/maven.html#class_activation), there are several ways to activate a profile in Maven2:

- Using a specific JDK,
- Using a specific OS,
- Giving a parameter in the command line,
- With a file...

So, as far as I know, there is no way to do what you want without creating a (simple) Mojo plugin...

Comment: I would do it then in a simple Mojo. 
Thanks